# How do I POST XML data to a URL via JavaScript in an Adobe AIR app?

Tags: php, javascript, xml, air

I'm writing an application that downloads an XML string from a URL and `POST`s that to another URL (that's set up to handle an incoming "`XML`" field). I've got the first part right - it downloads the XML and I can `alert()` it and all that, but I'm unable to figure out how to `POST` that data to a server.

```
function pull() {
    var myLoader = new air.URLLoader();
    var myRequest = new air.URLRequest('http://something/something.xml');
    myLoader.addEventListener(air.Event.COMPLETE, pulled);
    myLoader.load(myRequest);
}

function pulled(evt) {
    if (evt.target.bytesTotal>0) {
        // alerting shows the full string just fine
        alert(evt.target.data);

        var myLoader = new air.URLLoader();
        var myRequest = new air.URLRequest('http://someplace/push.php');
        myRequest.method = air.URLRequestMethod.POST;
        // myVars = new air.URLVariables("xml="+evt.target.data); // 
        // alert(evt.target.data.toUpperCase());
        myRequest.data = "xml="+evt.target.data; // myVars;
        myLoader.dataFormat = air.URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;
        myLoader.addEventListener(air.Event.COMPLETE, pushed);
        myLoader.load(myRequest);
    }
}
```

I made the 2nd server PHP `echo` the contents of the `xml` variable, but I'm just unable to get the exact contents of the XML string. There is something I'm doing wring with the `myRequest.data` and/or `dataFormat` bit.

Can someone just figure this out? I know it's probably a simple thing, but I'm at my wit's end right now.

This is my first AIR app.

Another related question (or sub-question) is that...

```
alert(evt.target.data);               // shows an alert box with the XML
alert(typeof evt.target.data);        // shows String
alert(evt.target.data.toUpperCase()); // shows the xml converted to upper case
alert(encodeURI(evt.target.data));    // shows up blank.
alert(escape(evt.target.data));       // shows up blank.
```

Why??

Comment: It can't be that difficult, can it??

Comment: The target is the Loader. The target.data is the data you set. -- so the first Alert shows that value.
The typeof shows 'string' because that's the type
The 'toUpper' - shows the string converted via the toUpperCase method
The 'encodeURI' fails - because the XML isn't in the right format
Not sure about the escape - sounds like it fails... Not sure why it's blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error seems to be the way you are assigning the parameters to 'data' ... Use URLVariables.

```
var params:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
params.[name of parameter] = [value];
```

--- so like params.xml = (YOUR XML) ... from your example:

```
// uses the dynamic object to add the 'xml' property to 'params' at runtime.
params.xml = evt.target.data
```

Then Change you request.data to request.data = params;

-- The URLVariables guy is dynamic - so you can add properties as I describe above.

For a basic example - much more complete that what I have here: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=data_access_2.html

Comment: I'm not actually using the content-type anywhere in the server either. I'm just taking in a string and running simplexml_load_string over it in the php.

Forget the fact that this is xml. Considering it's just text, what changes would I need to make to get it to post the data?

Comment: About how the data is expected, it's a simple `<FORM method="POST"...>` that I want to emulate. The code in the PHP uses a simple `$xml = $_POST['xml']` to access the post data. No content-type specs, no headers, nothing.

Comment: I remember trying something similar to what you just suggested, but I will try it again. Do I leave the `myLoader.dataFormat = air.URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT` intact or should I remove or change it to something else?

Comment: Yep. Leave it as URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT.

Comment: It's working! I removed the `myloader.dataFormat...` line (so it's taking the default value) and it's posting now.

Thanks!!!

Comment: Getting ready to hit the stack - if this doesn't work for you - post a comment and I'm happy to help tomorrow evening.